# How to run select queries when query parameters are selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

I wrote a sample program to fetch all articles. I would like to filter articles based on a category. The categories are rendered in a drop down, how do I fire a AJAX query when I select a category, so that the table refreshes immediately with that selection. Can you provide some references on how to achieve this?

```
select * from articles where category = <drop down selection>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing as following:

```
<%= select_tag :category,options_for_select(:your_collection)%>


 $('#category').bind('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: your_controller_action,
   data : {category: $('#category').val()}
   success: function(data){                  

        $('#your_replace_div_id').html(data);
        }        

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use js to get the category_id
`$('#category').options[$('#category').options.selectedIndex].value`

and then post this value to server by ajax

at server side, you can pass this category_id value into sql
`select * from articles where category = "#{category_id}"`